# Why for loop over a sqlalchemy.orm.collections.CollectionAdapter is extremly slow SQLAlchemy 1.1.18?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have the following objects definition:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class Project():
    __tablename__ = 'projects'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    qws = relationship('ProjectQWS',
                       foreign_keys='ProjectQWS.project_id',
                       cascade='all, delete-orphan',
                       order_by=ProjectQWS.is_main)

class ProjectQWS():

    __tablename__ = 'projects_qws'

    project_id = Column(
        Integer,
        ForeignKey('projects.id', name='fk_qws_project_id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
        primary_key=True,
    )
    qws_id = Column(String(QWS_ID_SIZE), nullable=False, primary_key=True)

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'project_id': self.project_id,
            'qws_id': self.qws_id,
        }
```

After querying for Project the for loop over qws collectionAdapter is extremely slow(couple of hundreds milliseconds. But this add up when I'm querying for 1000+ projcts) even if the qws  collection mostly contains 1 element (99% of the time).

```
def get_qws_dicts(self):
        result = []
        if self.qws:
            for qws_instance in self.qws:
                result.append(qws_instance.to_dict())
        return result
```

When the qws is empty the for loop is fast.

Any idea what is goin on here?

I use Postgress SQL , Python 3.6 and SQLAlchemy 1.1.18

Thanks

Comment: I think it has something to do with the way your query is loading references. Is the code you posted about ProjectQWSClass is complete, there is nothing more than this ? You could set your foreign key to load on select or join on query.

Comment: At the moment yes, that's the only thing i have in ProjectQWSClass. This is the projects query I'm using:  projects_query = self.db\
                .query(Project)\
                .join(ProjectQWS)\
                .filter(ProjectQWS.qws_id.in_(project_qws_ids))
projects = projects_query.all()

Comment: If i inspect in a debugger the qws collections content after running the query, i can see content in there. So I'm not sure it is a lazyloading issue here

Comment: Could it be your "order by" clause defined in the qws relationship ? I would try to disable it to see if it speeds up the loop

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference with the  order_by=ProjectQWS.is_main removed

Comment: My last idea, some kind of circular reference with your qws relationship ? Did you try to add a backref here ? EDIT : NVM, just read that backref will not changes anything, it's just a shortcut to what you already have. Maybe your loop is not using a connection pool and therefore open connection everytime. Would'nt it be cleaner to query qws list and then iterate ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just preload related model.
Please try something like this:

```
qws = relationship('ProjectQWS',
                       foreign_keys='ProjectQWS.project_id',
                       cascade='all, delete-orphan',
                       lazy='joined',
                       order_by=ProjectQWS.is_main)
```

Comment: I'm seeing a slight improvement with the lazy='joined', but not much. maybe about 10% faster.